# (I'm not uploading any file) The request message is too big. the server does not allow messages larger than 2097152

Tags: winforms, sharepoint-online, csom, caml

I have a simple list with 108 items, this code was working until today, but some how stop working with the message in the Title.

I'm only passing a simple CAML but I can´t ride of this error.

Anyone have a Suggestion? this is annoying.

```c
private static int GetLookupCity(string city)
{
    var oList = Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("City");
    var camlQuery = new CamlQuery
    {
        ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">" + city + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
    };
    var listItems = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
    Ctx.Load(listItems,
        items => items.Include(
            item => item["ID"],
            item => item["Title"]));
    Ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (var oListItem in listItems)
    {
        FieldLookupValue lv = new FieldLookupValue
        {
            LookupId = int.Parse(oListItem["ID"].ToString())
        };
        return lv.LookupId;
    }
    Ctx.Dispose();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It appears you have answered your own question and that is great, however, I have to ask… _”What is the purpose of the `foreach` loop?”_ … ? … The last line inside the loop is… `return lv.LookupId;` … This seems odd in a sense that if `listItems` is not empty, then it will ALWAYS return the FIRST item in the list. The `foreach` appears superfluous and the code could simply grab the FIRST item and return. Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this was already changed to ```var queryable = listItems.ToList().FirstOrDefault();``` and ```return queryable[0]["ID"]```

Answer (score 0):

I I'm using this in an Excel Addin, so It's not thread safe. The only way I can put this work was to use the Garbage Collector in all methods.

```c
private static int GetLookupCity(string city)
{
    var oList = Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("City");
    var camlQuery = new CamlQuery
    {
        ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">" + city + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
    };
    var listItems = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
    Ctx.Load(listItems,
        items => items.Include(
            item => item["ID"],
            item => item["Title"]));
    Ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    GC.Collect();
    var queryable = listItems.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
    FieldLookupValue lv = new FieldLookupValue
    {
        LookupId = int.Parse(queryable[0]["ID"].ToString())
    };
    return lv.LookupId;
   
    Ctx.Dispose();
    GC.Collect();
    return 0;
}
```